# Android Fragment replace own root view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have `FrameLayout` element in my `MainActivity`'s layout, what is used as "connection point" for multiple type of `Fragments`.

View:

```
 <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/main_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Fragment replace:

```
 Fragment fragment = new CoursesFragment();
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content, fragment).commit();
```

Now I'm at the situation I need change main_content directly from `CoursesFragment` (fragment replaces own view). What is best approach to do this? Is it safe? I can reach `MainActivity`'s context and change it, but I don't know if it's correct way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what your View is, but the simplest approach is to provide both Views inside their own ViewGroup, while setting 'the other view' on `setVisibility(View.GONE)`. If you need to switch, just set the first shown View to `View.GONE`, and the second to `View.VISIBLE`.

This way you don't have to hack around with the Activity's context, or Fragment Managers `hide` and `show` methods.

Comment: I have more than two fragments (views), It's awkward switching between them in that way.